# If every weak convergent sequence is norm convergent in a Hilbert space, does it imply that the space is separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

If in a Hilbert Space $H$, every  weakly convergent sequence is norm convergent does it imply that $H$ is separable?

I couldn't figure out the answer. The problem is I don't know example of inseparable Hilbert Space. so it is difficult for me to find a counter example if there is any.

I tried to prove the statement.

This is my attempt: If the space is finite dimensional we have nothing to prove.

If the space is infinite dimensional , we can have a orthonormal sequence say $(e_{n})$. We know $(e_{n})$ weakly converges to 0, but by hypotheses then $e_{n} \to 0$. From here, I can't proceed further. If I can prove that $H$ has a countable orthonormal basis, we are done. But I can't proceed further.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: As you noted, you should prove than an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space has an orthonormal sequence.  (You do not need an orthonormal basis.)  Hint: Gram-Schmidt

Comment: I don't understand! What I know is that  if a Hilbert space $H$ is separable, every orthonormal set ( in particular every orthonormal basis) is countable. And conversely, if a Hilbert space has a countable orthonormal basis, then the space is separable. So, what I want to prove is that given the conditions, $H$ has a countable basis!

Comment: An orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ has the property that $\|e_n\| = 1$. The claim that $\|e_n - 0\| \rightarrow 0$ is therefore absurd!

Comment: @TheoBendit that means that the question is absurd right? Because in any infinte dimensional Hilbert space there is always a sequence which is weak convergent but not norm convergent! So, the hypothesis is absurd!

Comment: @Riju Well, it means that if we have this property, then the space is finite-dimensional (which implies it's seperable). It just means the question could conclude something stronger.

Comment: @TheoBendit Got it!! Thanks